# SharedArrayBuffer will require cross-origin isolation as of M91, around May 2021

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

When creating a react app via `npx create-react-app` and running it, a warning pops up in DevTools (Chrome 88 and 89):

> scheduler.development.js:298 [Deprecation] SharedArrayBuffer will
> require cross-origin isolation as of M91, around May 2021. See
> https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer/ for
> more details.

**Environment**

```
  current version of create-react-app: 4.0.1
  running from /Users/mahdi/.npm/_npx/25767/lib/node_modules/create-react-app
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.15.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.10 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 88.0.4324.96
    Edge: 87.0.664.66
    Firefox: 84.0
    Safari: 14.0.2
  npmPackages:
    react: ^17.0.1 => 17.0.1
    react-dom: ^17.0.1 => 17.0.1
    react-scripts: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    create-react-app: Not Found
```

[image]

**Steps to reproduce**

1. `npx create-react-app myapp`
2. `cd myapp && npm start Open`
3. http://localhost:3000 in Chrome 88 or 89, regular or Incognito mode
4. Open DevTools: the warning is displayed

**Any suggestion for resolving this warning?**

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Update the `react` and `react-dom` versions from `17.0.1` to ==> `17.0.2` could resolve this problem.

You just need to run `npm update` in the command prompt or bash, and hopefully you will see the changes in your `package.json` file. (`yarn upgrade react --latest` and `yarn upgrade react-dom --latest` if you want the upgrade to persist to the `package.json`)

Here is a git report from my app after applying the update:

[image: image of git report]

Comment: I could still see the warning even after updating.

Comment: Did you restart your development server?

Comment: oh I didn't. It's working fine now (after restarting). Thanks much for your response!

Comment: "Don't forget to restart the server after updating npm packages."

Comment: We still get this error even though we've updated to 17.0.2 for react and react-dom and have restarted dev server

Comment: I too can still the error after updating 17.0.2 and restarting the server

Comment: I start a new project wit 17.0.2 and I still see this error... both React and react-dom.

Comment: my react app is still not cross origin isolated even after upgrading to v17.02. Even newly created app is not cross origin isolated. do you have any idea?

Answer (score 63):

As the warning shows, Chrome will require cross-origin isolation starting version 91 in order to use SharedArrayBuffer. As far as I know there is nothing you can do to resolve the warning other then wait for a react update.

Others are also having this issue as you can see [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20829) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10474)

The issue is fixed in [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/20831) pull request but has not yet been released.

**Edit:** It is now fixed in version 17.0.2 of react.

Answer (score 10):

Actually after update `react-dom` to the latest version solved by me the problem, `react` alone did not solve it:

```
npm i react@latest react-dom@latest
```

OR

```
yarn add react@latest react-dom@latest
```

Answer (score 8):

For those not ready to upgrade to v17 yet (due to other legacy libraries), a simple workaround is to place the following code in any part of your `index.html`

```html
    <script>
      // See https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20829#issuecomment-802088260
      if (!crossOriginIsolated) SharedArrayBuffer = ArrayBuffer;
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

### This issue has been fixed in React version 17.0.2
If you use also react-dom, you should also update it.
Running npm update (or corresponding command in yarn, or whatever manager you're using) will update everything, and so, solve the deprecation warning.

This is my package.json after update:

[image: screenshot from github desktop]

Answer (score 1):

I know you have got your answer, but if someone only use:
`npm i react@latest react-dom@latest` will not update react and react-dom to version 17.0.2 if current version react and react-dom is 16.x.x and your project is not EJECTED. That command is only update to react and react-dom to version 16.14.0. If you are in this case, you need to migrate react-script, react and react-dom version to 17 first: `npm install react-scripts@4.0.0 react@17.0.0 react-dom@17.0.0`.
More informations: https://dev.to/keonik/upgrading-to-react-17-create-react-app-edition-fe

Answer (score 1):

Update the react and react-dom versions to 17.0.2, `yarn upgrade react --latest` and `yarn upgrade react-dom --latest`

Also if using @hot-loader/react-dom or react-hot-loader, need to run `yarn upgrade @hot-loader/react-dom --latest` and `yarn upgrade react-hot-loader --latest` also.